# Statistics on car life length for each car model?

Tags: data-request, foia, cars

Authorities of each country register cars when they are bought or scrapped. Is there an open statistics of average life time for each car model?

Answer (score 1):

**United States of America**

The [Vehicle Inventory and Use Survey](http://www.census.gov/svsd/www/vius/products.html) conducted by the United States Census included the following information for trucks, which included SUV's and minivans:

- Vehicle Acquisition Month and Year
- Vehicle Make and Model Year
- Vehicle Disposal Month and Year

The data is predominantly truck focused as it was previously referred to as the Truck Use Survey, it was intermittent and was discontinued in 2002.

**Australia**

The [Motor Vehicle Census](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/9309.031%20Jan%202015?OpenDocument) provides statistics for vehicle type and vehicle characteristics including: make, manufacturer, and type of fuel. The free Excel file is good, but if you register with the [Australian Bureau of Statistics](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/D3310114.nsf/home/About+TableBuilder) you can build your own table using the microdata, which may include the length of ownerships from which you can start to build time series of ownership.

Note: In the United States, the Departments of Motor Vehicles for each state has the information you would like. They are very guarded about sharing this information.